# How to show the weak and weak* topology on the dual space of $c_{00}$ are not the same?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Equip $c_{00}$ with $\|\cdot\|_2$. I want to show the weak and weak* topology on the dual space of $c_{00}$ are not the same.

I know I can use the fact that a normed space $X$ is reflexive if and only if the weak and weak* topology on $X^*$ are the same. Since $c_{00}$ is not reflexive, the weak and weak* topology on the dual space of $c_{00}$ are not the same.

But my professor mentioned I should directly show the weak and weak* topology on the dual space of $c_{00}$ are not the same rather than using the simple fact.

So my question is how to construct the weak and weak* topology on the dual space of $c_{00}$ and show they are not the same? Thank you!

Comment: "So my question is how to construct the weak and weak* topology on the dual space of $c_{00}$" Do you not know the definitions of weak and weak* topology?

Comment: Which topology are you endowing $c_{00}$ with?

Comment: @DanielFischer♦ Sorry I forget to mention. Equip $c_{00}$ with $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Comment: So what are the dual and the bidual?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes I know. But I don't know what ${c_{00}}^*$ and ${c_{00}}^{**}$ look like.

Comment: @DanielFischer I only know ${c_{00}}^*\cong{\ell_2}^*$.

Comment: You should also know a bit about $\ell^2$ and its duals.

Comment: @DanielFischer The dual of $\ell_2$ is $\ell_2$. Can you help me show the weak and weak* topology on the dual space of $c_{00}$ are not the same.

Comment: The proof of the general fact that you quote (at least the proof that comes to my mind) shows you how to find a weakly open set that is not weak$^*$ open. Have you tried looking at your proof of the general fact and seeing if this helps?

Comment: @RhysSteele I tried but I am not sure what ${c_{00}}^*$ looks like. I only know ${c_{00}}^*\cong{\ell_2}^*$ and $\ell_2\cong{\ell_2}^*$. (Does this mean the element in ${c_{00}}^*$ is the same element in $\ell_2$?) Can you help me please?

Comment: You should also know what those isomorphisms are (i.e. be able to write down the maps explicitly). So you know an isomorphism $\Phi: \ell^2 \to c_{00}^*$ which means that you can think of the weak and weak$^*$ topologies as being on $\ell^2$ and elements of $\ell^2$ acting on $c_{00}$ via their image under $\Phi$.

Comment: @RhysSteele But it seems that construct there two topologies and prove a weakly open set is not weak* open are not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to show that the topologies are different is to find a sequence which converges in one topology but not the other.

Let $(e_n)_n$ be the canonical basis for $\ell^2 = (c_{00})^*$ and consider $(ne_n)_n$.

For an arbitrary $x = (x_n)_n \in c_{00}$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n = 0, \forall n \ge n_0$. Therefore for all $n \ge m_0$ we have
$$(ne_n)(x) = nx_n = 0$$
so $(ne_n)(x) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$.

Hence $ne_n \xrightarrow{w^*} 0$.

However, $\|ne_n\| = n$ so $(ne_n)_n$ is not a bounded sequence. Therefore, it cannot be weakly convergent in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! You saved my life! And based on your answer I add some details and post an answer below. Can you tell a look and see whether it is ok?

Comment: @AnswerLee Yeah, your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. This proof is my homework. And my professor wanted me to directly show $(f_{y_i})$ below does not convergence weakly in ${c_{00}}^*$. But it is really hard for me to do that without using every weakly convergent sequence is norm bounded. Can you give me a little hint? Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnswerLee Sure, it's easy: consider the functional $f\in(\ell^2)^{*} = \ell^2$ represented by the sequence $\left(\frac1{n^{3/4}}\right)_n$. Then $$f(ne_n) = n \cdot \frac1{n^{3/4}} = n^{1/4} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} +\infty$$
so $(ne_n)_n$ does not converge weakly in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But to be more accurate, I think we need to find $g\in {c_{00}}^*$ such that $g(f_{y_i})$ does not converge to 0. ($(f_{y_i})$ is the sequence we mentioned below.)

Comment: @AnswerLee No, we need to find $g \in (c_{00})^{**}$ such that $g(f_{y_i})$ does not converge to $0$. I found a $g$ such that $g(f_{y_i})$ converges to infinity. You can also take $g$ represented by $\left(\frac1n\right)_n$ so you get $g(f_{y_i}) = \frac1{i} \cdot i = 1$ so it converges to $1$.

Comment: Yes I had a typo. But I mean we only have $(c_{00})^{**}\cong\ell_2$. How can we get $g(f_{y_i})=1$? I think we need some certain map to get it.

Comment: @AnswerLee Define $g \in (c_{00})^{**}$ as $g(f) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1nf(e_n)$ for every $f \in (c_{00})^*$. We have $$g(f_{y_i}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n f_{y_i}(e_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n y_n^i = \frac1i \cdot i = 1 $$

Comment: Thank you for your patience. But why we can define $g(f)$ like that?

Comment: @AnswerLee An element of $(c_{00})^{**}$ is a bounded linear functional on the space of bounded linear functionals on $c_{00}$. So this particular $g \in (c_{00})^{**}$ takes $f \in (c_{00})^*$ and assigns it a scalar $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n f(e_n)$. It is easy to see that $g$ is linear and it is also bounded:
$$|g(f)| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n f(e_n)\right| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n |f(e_n)| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \|f\|  = \frac{\pi^2}6\|f\|$$

Comment: Thank you so much. If that possible I have your email so that I can send you some details of the proof I add. Of course if you feel comfortable. Appreciate again!!

Comment: @AnswerLee You can create a new chatroom like this one [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79858/discussion-between-answer-lee-and-mechanodroid) we had.

Comment: The latex code is too long to add in the comment. So I edit my answer below and I add some detail based your answer. Can you take a loot and see whether it is ok or not? Thank you!

Comment: @AnswerLee Everything looks correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is that necessary to show our $g$ is well defined?

Comment: @AnswerLee If you know that $(c_{00})^{**} \cong \ell^2$ and how the isomorphism looks, then just say let $g$ be a functional represented by $\left(\frac1n\right)_n \in \ell^2$, and it is then clear that it is well defined. If you don't wish to use the isomormphism then you have to manually prove linearity and boundedness, as you did.

Comment: Hi I find a little error $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\neq\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. And it is divergent.

Comment: @AnswerLee Indeed, I made a mistake in the above proof  that $g$ is bounded. You can prove it like this: first notice that for $f\in (c_{00})^*$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(e_n)|^2 \le \|f\|^2$. Indeed:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(e_k)\right|^2\right)^2 = \left|f\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \overline{f(e_k)}e_k\right)\right|^2 \le \|f\|^2 \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n \overline{f(e_k)}e_k\right\|_2^2 = \|f\|^2 \sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(e_k)\right|^2$$
so $\sum_{k=1}^n \left|f(e_k)\right|^2 \le \|f\|^2, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and letting $n\to\infty$ gives $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|f(e_k)\right|^2 \le \|f\|^2$.

Comment: Now we have

$$|g(f)| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n f(e_n)\right| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n |f(e_n)| \stackrel{CSB}\le \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|f(e_k)\right|^2} \le \sqrt{\frac{\pi^2}6}\sqrt{\|f\|^2} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt6}\|f\|$$

Answer (score 1):

Based on @mechanodroid 's answer. I add some details.

To show $\sigma(X^*,X)\neq\sigma(X^*,X^{**})$ for $X=(c_{00},\|\cdot\|_2)$, we only need to find a weak* convergent sequence in ${c_{00}}^*$ that does not converge weakly in ${c_{00}}^*$.

Let $y=(y_n)\in\ell_2$. Then $f_y(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ny_n$ ($x=(x_n)\in c_{00}$) defines a bounded linear functional on $c_{00}$.
In fact, $\phi:\ell_2\rightarrow {c_{00}}^*,y\mapsto f_y$ is an isometric isomorphism. Let $y_i=(y_n^i)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  ($i\in\mathbb{N}$) where $(y_n^i)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence in $\mathbb{F}$ whose $i$th element is $i$ and other elements are $0$. Then $(y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $\ell_2$. Thus $(f_{y_i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in ${c_{00}}^*$. Let $x=(x_n)\in c_{00}$. Then there exists $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=0$ for all $n\geqslant N_0$. Thus for all $i\geqslant N_0$, $f_{y_i}(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x_ny_n^i=ix_i=0$. It follows that $\lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}f_{y_i}(x)=0$. Hence, $f_{y_i}\overset{wk^*}{\longrightarrow}0$. 
    Let $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\|y_i\|_2=(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n^i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=i$. Since $\ell_2\cong {c_{00}}^*$, $\lim\limits_{i\rightarrow\infty}\|f_{y_i}\|=\|y_i\|_2=\infty$. Thus $(y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not norm bounded in ${c_{00}}^*$. Hence, $(y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge weakly in ${c_{00}}^*$.

We can also show $(f_{y_i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge weakly to $0$ in ${c_{00}}^*$ directly:

Since $\ell_2\cong {c_{00}}^*$, for each $f\in {c_{00}}^*$, there exists $y\in\ell_2$ such that $f=f_y$, and thus we can use $f_y$ to present the element in ${c_{00}}^*$. Define $g:{c_{00}}^*\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$ by $g(f_y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}y_n$ ($y=(y_n)\in\ell_2$). Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$ and let $f_x,f_y\in{c_{00}}^*$ ($x=(x_n)\in\ell_2$ and $y=(y_n)\in\ell_2$). Then $$g(f_x+\alpha f_y)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}(x_n+\alpha y_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}x_n+\alpha\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}y_n=g(f_x)+\alpha g(f_y).$$ Hence, $g$ is linear. Let $f_y\in{c_{00}}^*$ ($y=(y_n)\in\ell_2$). Then $$|g(f_y)|=|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}y_n|\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}|y_n|\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\|f_y\|=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\|f_y\|.$$ Thus $g$ is a linear bounded functional on ${c_{00}}^*$; that is, $g\in{c_{00}}^{**}$. For all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $g(f_{y_i})=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}y_n^i=1$. Hence, $(f_{y_i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge weakly to $0$ in ${c_{00}}^*$.